# Android ADT - Disable "use same device for future launches"

Tags: android, adt

How can I uncheck the "use same device for future launches"?

[image: The checkbox that I want to uncheck]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Right click on your project, and go to `Run As -> Run Configurations`.

[image]

Then, under `Android Application -> (Your Project)`, go to the `Target` tab, and check the first radio option `Always prompt to pick device`.

[image]

Comment: I am sorry but the "Always prompt to pick device is already selected but the window doesn't show itself. so this answer is not right. Can you try it yourself?

Comment: I did try it myself before posting the answer. I'm not sure why it wouldn't work for you. Are you running your app on a device or emulator?

Comment: Running the app on both emulator and a device. What was it before you chose "Always prompt.."?

Comment: I would suggest disabling adb on your device and shutting down the emulator. Then, click on the Run button, which will force the prompt to appear. You should be able to uncheck the box then

Comment: What OS do you use? I use Mac. Maybe it's a bug on mac computers

Comment: I'm using Windows. Does the prompt not appear if you have no devices connected?

Comment: outdated answer, should be removed

Answer (score 16):

In Android Studio: Menu `Run`  ->  `Edit Configurations`

[image: Edit Configurations]

and here in `app` tab uncheck "Use same device for future launches"

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Bottom line: my ADT on Mac environment has some sort of a bug.

Edit: This "bug" is fixed on OSX Yosemite and Eclipse Luna

Answer (score 0):

If you are using eclipse JUNO, exit from eclipse and it will be disabled. When you run eclipse again, and debug your project, you will prompted again for pick device and you can select another device.