# How to choose the device when starting an app from AndroidStudio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I have 2 emulators (2 avd) created in AndroidStudio. Both are working.

I have started my app in AVD 1. I was asked which device to choose.
Now I would like to start the app in AVD 2, but it starts always again with AVD 1.

How can I force AndroidStudio to ask me every time I start the App. Do I really have to close AVD1 to run it in AVD2 ?

Comment: refer this http://stackoverflow.com/a/21973084/2809326

Comment: Looks like eclipse answer. I am using AndroidStudio as the title says.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Edit Configurations ->General -> Deployment Target Option -> Target -> Open Select Deployment Target Dialog :

[image]

Comment: Strange. I have exactly these settings. Also Use same device is unchecked. But still when launching the app it launches in the only open device I have -> AVD1. Any ideas whats wrong ?

Comment: Create new Debug Configurations and test.

Comment: You are right. When creating a new configuration it works. Strange, but solved it, thanks.